# Confusion about scanner, filewriter and getClass().getResource()

Tags: java

Apologies if this is a basic question.

I'm trying to read and from a text file (into and from an array list). I'm trying to get it to work with relative locations, but I get 2 exceptions:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(getClass().getResource("/saved/test.txt")); //reading
```

The constructor Scanner(URL) is undefined.

And similarly when I save data:

```
FileWriter fw= new FileWriter(getClass().getResource("/saved/test.txt"));//saving
            for (String s : names) {
                fw.write(s + "\n");
            }
            fw.close();
```

The constructor FileWriter(URL) is undefined.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: If your aim is to read and write Lists to text files, think about using FileUtils from commons io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getClass().getResource()` reads resources from the classpath. Not files from the current directory.

To get a file relative to the current directory, just use

```
new File("saved/test.txt");
```

Comment: But I'm working with eclipse. By using your suggestion, I have to create a folder outside of src folder. I wish to use a folder called "saved" which is at the root of my src folder.

Comment: I know that "src/saved/test.txt" would work but I want a more robust relative filepath...

Comment: src is for source files. A file that your program reads and writes is not a source file. It's data. BTW, the fact you're using eclipse is irrelevant. When your program is executed on an end-user's machine, there won't be any src directory anywhere.

Comment: Got it. So it wouldn't be advisable to save into the "src" folder.

Comment: How could I go about "pre-creating" this file then? Since if the file doesn't previously exist, I will get a run time exception when trying to read from it. Or what would be the most robust way of managing this file (creating, reading and writing to it)?

Comment: How about testing if the file exists before reading it, instead of pre-creating it? Read the javadoc of File.